# VB.NET How would i get contents from a listbox and add them into a textbox one at a time automatically

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox

Okay, long title i know but im in need of some help.

i have not got any code at the moment because i do not know where to start.

here is what i need to do:

i need to move the first line of text from a listbox to the textbox
then wait a few seconds and move to the second line of text, then wait a few seconds and move to the third, so on and so fourth.

its for a program i have in mind that i want to work on but am still stuck on this one part.

Please help me, been stuck for about 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
For Each objItem As Object In Me.ListBox1.Items
    Me.TextBox1.Text = objItem.ToString
    Me.TextBox1.Refresh()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000) 'wait 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
Next objItem
```

Comment: Holy crap, working like a charm so far, ill let you know if it works for what i intent! <3